# Understanding the RFC1918 IP address range

Tags: networking, ip, squid

Short version, what does it exactly mean, `192.168.1.0/24`, or `192.168.0.0/16`?

Long version, I want to [restrict my Squid server's Web Access By IP Address](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch32_:_Controlling_Web_Access_with_Squid#Restricting_Web_Access_By_IP_Address), and the article shows two ways,

```
acl home_network src 192.168.1.0/24
```

or,

```
acl home_network src 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
```

what exactly does those IP address range mean?
and how about `192.168.0.0/16`?

If my IP address is `192.168.2.xx`, and my route is `192.168.2.0`, can I use `192.168.0.0/16`?

Thanks

Comment: [Classless Inter-Domain Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) aka CIDR Notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Both `/24` and `255.255.255.0` mean the same in terms of subnetting.

### Longer answer

Basically the first one is the CIDR representation of the second. The `/24` makes reference to the number of binary `1`s in the second form. So if you have:

```
255.255.255.0
```

In binary that is:

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.0
```

You'll see there are 24 ones, which is represented by the `/24` notation. There is a lot of documentation about subnetting, but if you're using the `192.168.2.X` range, you'll want to use the mentioned `/24` subnet mask as it will mean that only the last octet (the one I named `X`) will vary.

I recommend reading [this](https://www.techopedia.com/6/28587/internet/8-steps-to-understanding-ip-subnetting) for understand better the subnetting subject.

Comment: Thank you both, Ron Maupin & nKn. So, if my IP address is `192.168.2.xx`, and my route is `192.168.2.0`, I **can** use `192.168.0.0/16`, right?

Comment: Yes, you can, but that would also mean that any number matching the third octet would be valid too. That means that if a user with IP address `192.168.15.1` (for instance) accesses the service, it would be valid. If you want to enforce the number `2` in the third octet, you would better use the `/24`.

Answer (score 2):

There are three RFC 1918 networks:

- `10.0.0.0/8`
- `172.16.0.0/12`
- `192.168.0.0/16`

You can subnet within each one of those ranges. For instance, `192.168.1.0/24` is a subnet within the `192.168.0.0/16` network. So is what you say you use: `192.168.2.0/24`.

It all boils down to binary math. The mask length, the number after`/`, is the number of bits in the 32-bit IP address which belong to the network/subnet. The remaining bits, `32 - <mask length>` is the number of bits for the host addresses.